# In Python I want to access a text file while it is being updated by another program

Tags: python-3.x

`if __name__ == "__main__":`
`with open("log.txt", 'r') as f:`
`content = f.readlines()`
`for i, line in enumerate(content):`

I am using above code to read text file. But it only gets current data

Comment: (Note you can use block formatting to format multiple lines Chinmay. Select the code and click the 'code' button).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on operating system, you have a couple of choices.

1. Check if the file has changed since last time.
2. In Linux there is this "new" functionality that will inform you of changes made to a file.

It was a while back since I tried to work with something similar and guess what, there is this package you can use that has solved this problem.

I believe it was this package I used, not sure. But the documentation claims to give you some methods to use:
http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/